# text not showing up on plot in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe named `tab` of the following format:

```
  Var1  Freq
1    5  1853
2   15  2862
3   25  7206
4   35 14890
5   45 19856
6   55 23837
7   65 16510
8   75  4729
9   85   830
```

I want to make a barplot and have the `Freq` displayed on the bar.

I have tried the following:

```
plot(tab$Var1, tab$Freq)

text(
    x      = tab$Var1, 
    y      = tab$Freq, 
    labels = row.names( tab$Freq ),
    adj    = 0)
```

There seems to be two things wrong here:

1. The plot is showing lines instead of bars, and `barplot(tab$Freq)
   axis(1, xaxp = tab$Var1)` gives error that `Error in axis(1, xaxp = tab$Var1) : plot.new has not been called yet` (PART 1 SOLVED).
2. Using the original `plot` and `text` function, the texts do not show up.

Thanks.

Comment: `tab.Freq` doesn't have row names. Change `row.names(tab$Freq)` to `row.names(tab)`.

Comment: This worked fine for me: `barplot(dat$Freq, names.arg = dat$Var1)`.

Comment: Got the names. Thanks Gregor and lmo

Comment: `pos` in `text()` might be a factor which causes the text disappear. Setting `pos` as 1, 2, 3 or 4 is possible solution for this kind of problem. pos is described in `?text() `.  e.g. `text(x=mean(vector_x), y=mean(vector_y), pos=4, labels="1")`